# Обеспечить связь lua скрипта с сервером

Tags: lua

Необходимо, чтобы на клиентской стороне скрипт получал данные и отправлял их для последующей обработки на сервер, где выполняется главная работа. От туда же получает ответ. Какие технологии использовать? Как защитить соединение? Бегло побегал по гуглу, но особо ничего не нашел.

Буду очень признателен за развернутый ответ.

Comment: https://github.com/brunoos/luasec/wiki

Comment: Если лень разбираться с SSL-библиотеками, то просто через `io.popen()` запусти wget/curl и передай POST-запрос https-сайту и получи ответ

Comment: Самым верным будет использование luasocket